# Can't access my old Homegroup, neither create a new

Tags: windows, networking, home-networking

Upgraded to Win 10. Now All PCs are not connected to any Homegroup, but the Homegroup still exists. I can't access because I dunno the password, neither create a new Homegroup. Any ideas how to fix this? I still research but I couldn't find a solution right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the Homegroup Service, and starting again fixed it for me. Sorry for the panic post.